# Dependency Injection Framework - Dependency Propogation

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection

I understand what Dependency Injection is but I still don't see the full picture yet in terms of how it benefits the consumer. See example below.

```
//bad
class car () {
  var tire = new Tire('snow');
}

//good
class car () {
  var tire;
  constructor(tire){
    this.tire=tire
  }
}
```

So most articles I have read state that the above example is good since it eliminates the tire dependency from car and thus becomes more testable. But what about the other class that instantiates a car object. If a `driver` class was to summon a `car` class would that not force the driver to instantiate `car` object and the `tires` as well. It seems like as though the dependency always gets propagated further up. Where does this end? What actually instantiates objects? Is this what DI frameworks are all about?

Comment: In a nutshell: yes, it "propagates up" all the way, and yes, that is what DI frameworks are there to simplify.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the dependency requirements get "propagated up" all the way. The driver wanting to instantiate their car needs to bring the `Car` and the `Tire`s. A driver pool with many drivers would need to bring the `Driver`s, `Car`s and `Tire`s and so on and so forth. The simple way to combat that is bundling things into a factory:

```
class Driver {
    constructor(carFactory) {
        this.car = carFactory.newCarWithRegularTires();
    }
}
```

<sub>(Only for illustrative purposes, see below.)</sub>

You can inject a different factory which can create other cars, and the dependency of a `Car` can change without `Driver` needing to be aware of any of this.

Taken a step further, you can create a general global factory which can create all kinds of objects and knows how to satisfy the dependencies of each, which is a dependency injection container. You typically configure them in a textual format, declaring that a `Car` needs a `Tire`, and when you ask it for an instance of `Car` it knows to instantiate a `Tire` first and pass it.

The disadvantage of a DI container is that while you can still swap dependencies simply by reconfiguring the DI container, that sometimes means you have to reconfigure the entire thing and it becomes a giant interdependent object registry. You should avoid creating one giant über-container, but keep things modular.

Another word on factories: the above factory example isn't great. An object should use a factory if it needs to create new instances of objects at runtime. It should *not* use a factory simply to satisfy a dependency that could be injected directly.

In the end you want to strike a balance between classes declaring and receiving their dependencies directly, but also not creating extremely deep dependency hierarchies. Keeping dependencies as shallow as possible is a good start, introducing factories or modular DI containers at stategic points is another way.

Comment: Great answer. To verify my understanding, you are saying that instantiating objects is inevitable. It's all about keeping the dependency hierarchy as simple and as shallow as possible and using factories when needed. Do you have any rules of thumb that would generally guide you when doing so?

Comment: Not beyond "when it starts to become a pain, step back and refactor." – Objects should directly take their dependencies in their constructor, which basically defines your dependency graph, which gets wider and wider towards the top. DI containers/factories narrow the graph again, but also introduce more bundling and become somewhat harder to replace. Pick strategic spots on your graph for them wherever it seems suitable.